# Reverse engineering ARM PIC

Tags: arm, ios

I'm starting to learn reverse engineering so I'm trying to reverse sample app, compiled for ARM(iOS) and now I'm looking into code.

This section is right before `WHILE` and right at the beginning of function where values are initiated. but I can't find the raw values.

This is the function .h file:

```
#import "NSObject.h"

@interface SampleCalc : NSObject

+ (double)doCalc:(double)arg1;

@end
```

And this is the ARM code:

```
+[SampleCalc doCalc:]:
0002f198         movw       sb, #0x6cb4      ; Objective C Implementation defined at 0x95db8 (class method), :lower16:(0xc5e60 - 0x2f1ac)
0002f19c         vmov.i32   d18, #0x0
0002f1a0         movt       sb, #0x9         ; :upper16:(0xc5e60 - 0x2f1ac)
0002f1a4         vmov       d16, r2, r3
0002f1a8         add        sb, pc           ; 0xc5e60
0002f1aa         movs       r2, #0x0
0002f1ac         add.w      r3, sb, #0x8     ; 0xc5e68
0002f1b0         vldr       d17, [sb]
```

If I understand correctly this is ARM PIC (position independent code).

But I don't get the logic here `0002f1b0` - does the brackets mean `sb` is storing address and value is loaded in `d17`? And what is the address - `0xc5e68` correct?

The `0xc5e60` contains:

```
000c5e60         db  0x00 ;
000c5e61         db  0x00 ; '.'
000c5e62         db  0x00 ; '.'
000c5e63         db  0x00 ; '.'
000c5e64         db  0x00 ; '.'
000c5e65         db  0x00 ; '.'
000c5e66         db  0x33 ; '3'
000c5e67         db  0x40 ; '@'
000c5e68         db  0x00 ;
000c5e69         db  0x00 ; '.'
000c5e6a         db  0x00 ; '.'
000c5e6b         db  0x00 ; '.'
000c5e6c         db  0x00 ; '.'
000c5e6d         db  0x00 ; '.'
000c5e6e         db  0x34 ; '4'
000c5e6f         db  0x40 ; '@'
000c5e70         db  0x00 ; '.'
000c5e71         db  0x00 ; '.'
000c5e72         db  0x00 ; '.'
000c5e73         db  0x00 ; '.'
000c5e74         db  0x00 ; '.'
000c5e75         db  0x00 ; '.'
000c5e76         db  0x35 ; '5'
```

So does that mean `D17` gets value `0x00`?

Bonus question, if possible, what are all those `.` and `@`.

Thanks.

Comment: What tool is the output from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sb` is the alternative name for the ARM register `R9` used by some disassemblers, similar to `ip` for `R12`, `sp` for `R13` or `PC` for `R15`.

The main thing you need to look at is this:

```
0002f1a8         add        sb, pc
```

At this point, `sb` has the value of 0x96cb4 due to the `movw` and `movt` before.
In ARM, the `pc` value points two instructions ahead, so here it will have value 0x002f1a8+4 = 0x002f1ac. So, we get 0x002f1ac+0x96cb4=0xC5E60 which matches the comment added by the disassembler. Next, `vldr d17, [sb]` is executed which loads the double value at `sb` (or 0xC5E60). Double values are 8 bytes long so all of the bytes from 0xC5E60 till 0xC5E67 will be loaded. The hex for it is 0x4033000000000000 which [corresponds to 19.0](http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754.old/64bit.html).